# Are PL/SQL stored procedures transactions?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, transactions

Are PL/SQL stored procedures transactions? 
When a trigger, procedure or function runs, is it a transaction? 
I usually end my procedures with `COMMIT` and when an error occurs I use `ROLLBACK`! Is it wrong?

I'am not asking about `START TRANSACTION` into procedures but I want to know if they are transactions.

Thank you.

Comment: if your query has been solved marke the question as answered :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Are PL/SQL stored procedures transactions? When a trigger, procedure or function runs, is it a transaction?`

No. A transaction starts with the first DML encountered and ends when it encounters a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. A transaction can comprise many function and procedure calls and DML statements and trigger code. On the other hand, you can create a procedure that comprises of many transactions by issuing lots of COMMITs.

`I usually end my procedures with COMMIT and when an error occurs I use ROLLBACK! Is it wrong?`

Wrong is a strong word. Let's just say it's not a good practice. Making (packaged) functions and procedures is all about modularization: making reusable pieces of code. When a function/procedure contains ROLLBACK or COMMIT statements, it stops being reusable as it messes up the transaction of the caller. So it's better not to use ROLLBACK or COMMIT in your procedures and leave it to the topmost caller.

You could use SAVEPOINTS throughout your code which makes sure a single function or procedure doesn't leave open parts of a transaction. But for esthetical reasons I prefer to not use SAVEPOINTS. For me, it's just five lines of unnecessary code, because I know my caller function will handle the transaction just nicely.

Exception is when you create an autonomous procedure, which is by definition a single transaction and thus needs to end with a COMMIT.

**UPDATE**

Note that a RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR or a RAISE [exception name] statement will also automatically rollback your PL/SQL block as a single atomic unit. Which is of course a desirable effect as it doesn't leave you with uncommitted changes.

```
SQL> create table mytable (id int)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create procedure p
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    insert into mytable values (2);
  5    raise_application_error(-20000,'My exception');
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select *
  2    from mytable
  3  /

no rows selected

SQL> insert into mytable values (1)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> exec p
BEGIN p; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: My exception
ORA-06512: in "X.P", regel 5
ORA-06512: in regel 1


SQL> select *
  2    from mytable
  3  /

        ID
----------
         1

1 row selected.
```

Comment: 1) You said a transaction starts with the first DML encountered, so if I write a procedure wich starts with `SELECT` and ends with `COMMIT`, have I made a transaction?
2) A `ROLLBACK` after `RAISE APPLICATION ERROR` will not be realized?

Comment: 2) RAISE statements also end your transaction, indeed. I updated the post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Can you answer at the first question?

Comment: 1) That would be an empty transaction if there is no DML in between.

Comment: Technically speaking, you're right. And if the select contains a FOR UPDATE clause, you're absolutely right. So you might want to read "DML" as "DML statements that modify the database".

Comment: A point of clarification. An unhandled exception will rollback your transaction **only if the exception is propagated all the way out to the calling anonymous block**. From the Oracle documentation "If you exit a stored subprogram with an unhandled exception, PL/SQL does not .. do any rollback". The rollback is not performed as part of the `RAISE`/`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` statement.

Comment: The rollback is performed because a PL/SQL unit is viewed as an atomic piece of code, which either succeeds completely or not at all. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Off course its not a transaction but a modification. And you dont need to specify Commit everytime to save your transaction. 
In Oracle for example all individual DML statements are atomic (i.e. they either succeed in full, or rollback any intermediate changes on the first failure) (unless you use the EXCEPTIONS INTO option, which I won't go into here).
Consider an example above:
If you wish a group of statements to be treated as a single atomic transaction, you'd do something like this:

```
BEGIN
  SAVEPOINT start_tran;
  INSERT INTO .... ; -- first DML
  UPDATE .... ; -- second DML
  BEGIN ... END; -- some other work
  UPDATE .... ; -- final DML
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK TO start_tran;
    RAISE;
END;
```

That way, any exception will cause the statements in this block to be rolled back, but any statements that were run prior to this block will not be rolled back.

Note that I don't include a COMMIT - usually I prefer the calling process to issue the commit.

Comment: If you wanted the procedure to do the commit rather than a caller, where would you place that commit in the sample below?  Thank you

Answer (score -1):

PL/SQL is a Modification, not a transaction. A Transaction is a list of Modifications and Read-only operations. If you have a

```
update
insert
pl/sql
update
rollback
```

the PL/SQL will not make a change to the database, even if the pl/sql is executed.

Comment: This is not correct. A transaction is a process wich includes also read only operations.